# How to include a standalone jar that uses spring and beans as a dependency in maven project for jenkins plugin?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, jar, jenkins-plugins

I want to include a standalone jar file (which uses spring), inside my java code to develop a jenkins plugin. When I add this as a dependency and I run the plugin ,I get errors like: Caused: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [com/XXX/YYY/jmsclient3/XXXclient-jms-config.xml]
It says cant find the class path resource [com/XXX/YYY/jmsclient3/XXXclient-jms-config.xml], because it doesnt exist.
But this file is clearly there in the jar. Its a bean file(I dont know much about it).

Comment: This does not sound like a good idea. It would be better to create a third project that you can use both a library for you spring application and for the jenkins plugin.

Comment: @JFabianMeier Actually I have no idea about spring. This jar that I want to use has spring used inside it. When I use this jar in standalone java project, it works totally fine.
But in case of maven project for jenkins plugin, the plugin cant find the resources during the execution of plugin on jenkins local server and gives this classpath error.
Can you please help me with what to do and how to do it?